# Password field not taking keys using Selenium through Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to send keys via selenium it is taking for username but not for password.

I have tried clicking and sending keys then.

HTML of password field:

```
<div>
    <input name="txtPassword" type="password" id="txtPassword" required="" style="margin-bottom:0px;" class="blur">
    <a id="btnSmallForgotPassword" class="smallForgotPassword visible-sm-block" href="javascript:__doPostBack('btnSmallForgotPassword','')">forgot password</a>
</div>
```

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtPassword"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID,"txtPassword"))).send_keys("san")
```

I am getting no error message but it is not sending keys for password

Comment: it worked once or twice but fails after sometime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this **code** :

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtPassword"))).send_keys('your_password')
```

You should not create object of WebDriverWait too many times, use it like this :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtPassword"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtPassword"))).send_keys('your_password')
```

and `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtPassword")))` returns a web element, where you can use methods like `click(), clear(), send_keys()` etc.

You can write your code like this also :

```
password_field = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtPassword")))
password_field.click()
password_field.send_keys('your_password')
```

**EDIT1 :**

You can use this css selector :

```
input[id='txtPassword']
```

**EDIT 2 :**

You can use this full method :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://backgriduk.medialava.com/pages/Staff/Login.aspx?LANGUAGE_ID=3&O=7")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[id='txtUser']"))).send_keys("abhishek")

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtPassword"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"txtPassword"))).send_keys('your_password')
```

Comment: It is also not working I am attaching the website trying to scrape http://backgriduk.medialava.com/pages/Staff/Backlog.aspx?AUTH_TOKEN=QVVUSF9LRVlfT1JHQU5JWkFUSU9OX0lEPTd8LXxBVVRIX0tFWV9VU0VSX0lEPTUyOTF8LXxBVVRIX0tFWV9JUD0xMTQuMTQzLjMxLjIwMnwtfEFVVEhfS0VZX0NPT0tJRV9OQU1FPUZBTl82MzY1NjgwMjQyMjUyMTAwMDB8LXxBVVRIX0tFWV9DT09LSUVfTlVNQkVSPTUyMjJ8LXxBVVRIX0tFWV9ET01BSU49L3wtfEFVVEhfS0VZX1RJTUU9My8xNi8yMDE4IDE6MDc6MDIgUE18LXw1&LANGUAGE_ID=3

Comment: EDIT 2 you can use too for more stability.

Comment: It should work fine , though I'm not clicking on login button.

Comment: Thanks but sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I don't know whay it is behaving like that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('http://backgriduk.medialava.com/pages/Staff/Login.aspx?LANGUAGE_ID=3&O=7')
time.sleep(3)

username = driver.find_element_by_id("txtUser")
username.clear()
# insert username
username.send_keys("mrcats")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("txtPassword")
password.clear()
# insert password
password.send_keys("catskillz")

login = driver.find_element_by_name("btnLogin")
#click on login button
login.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work.However I have tested following code on chrome browser and working fine.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://backgriduk.medialava.com/pages/Staff/Login.aspx?LANGUAGE_ID=3&O=7')
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'txtUser'))).send_keys("Abhishek")
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'div.divInnerRightControls #txtPassword'))).send_keys("Abhishek")
```

Output:
[image: Login form]

Answer (score 0):

To send *character sequence* to the **USER ID** and **PASSWORD** field you need to to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\geckodriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://backgriduk.medialava.com/pages/Staff/Login.aspx?LANGUAGE_ID=3&O=7")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#txtUser"))).send_keys("abhishek_gupta")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#txtPassword").send_keys("abhishek_gupta")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: userid_password]

Comment: Hi Debanjan your solution sometimes work and sometimes it does'nt.

Comment: @abhishekgupta A bit unclear to me what you exactly mean by _...sometimes work and sometimes it doesn't..._ :) If it works once, it will always work unless the system RAM and memory requirements falls short. Btw, do you see any error?

Comment: I do not see any error it simply doesn't send keys to password.

Comment: @abhishekgupta Are you sure you are triggering the tests on a clean slate without any dangling webdriver instances?